# Allowing anonymous access to Google Apps Script web app (Google Apps account)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a spreadsheet in my Google Drive that I would like to share through a web app. I want the script to run as me and allow everyone to access the web app.

When this is done in my personal Google account (non Google App account), I get "Anyone, even anonymous" option under "Who has access to the web app" section in the "Publish as a web app" dialog in the Apps Script editor. And everything works fine.

However when I try to do the same thing in my Google Apps account in my organization, I do not get "Anyone, even anonymous" option under "Who has access to the web app" section. Only options that are presented is "Only myself" & "Anyone within XXXXXXX.com"

Anybody have any idea why this is happening? Is there any security option that I can change in my Google Apps domain?

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?  I'm running up against the same problem, but wasn't able to find the answer in the posted document in the answer (and looked over each setting 10 times now)

Comment: [tag:google-apps] is about applications from Google. For questions about "administered accounts" ("Google Apps Free" and G Suite), use [tag:gsuite].

Comment: What you can do instead is create a script on your personal account to receive the spreadsheet information and display it on your personal account, and in your managed account you send the data to the personal account's script via HTTP requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you checked with your Google Apps Administrator? They might have enforced a policy that one can not share the docs outside the organization.

Here is the documentation on docs sharing policy.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

This setting is controlled by the domain administrator via the "Allow users in [domain] to publish files on the web or make them visible to the world as public or unlisted files" options that's under "Settings for Drive and Docs".

Note that after checking that option, you'll have to create a new Script in order to be able to publish it with "Anonymous" access. Existing scripts don't seem to get that option even after the setting has been changed.

Also note the Google issue tracker for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764781

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this answer!