# Allowing anonymous access to very specific Google Apps Script web apps

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, publish, google-workspace

First, this question **is** similar to [Allowing anonymous access to Google Apps Script web app (Google Apps account)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928411/allowing-anonymous-access-to-google-apps-script-web-app-google-apps-account) but my question is more specific and the other question is marked with an answer that does not answer my question so **please do not mark this question as a duplicate.**

Our organization is on G-Suite Enterprise. We currently have our sharing options for "Drive and Docs" set to "WHITELISTED DOMAINS".

I want to share one **very specific** Google Apps Script web-app with the public/anonymous.

We do not want to change the sharing options for "Drive and Docs" to "ON", as outlined at https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en under "Allow users to publish files publicly", as that is a global setting and would allow users to share any/ever file/web-app.

Is there a way to set this setting for a very specific web-app? I'm wondering if maybe there is a way to use groups to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

One option is to use an account outside your G Suite domain to create the web application.

Comment: We can't use groups or creating a new organization?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Please try that and share with us your findings.

Comment: Ha. I'm in a Catch-22. I can't convince my org admins to let me try it without showing them evidence that it'll work. Heh.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan How about setting up a test organization using the G Suite trial period?